# Sorting an object in descending order using Array.sort and Lambda Expression

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort a collection of objects in descending order.

Below code is working to sort the itemDetails object in ascending order.

```
Arrays.sort(itemDetails, (a, b) -> 
    String.valueOf(a.getAvailableQuantity())
          .compareTo(String.valueOf(b.getAvailableQuantity())));
```

But I wanted the output in descending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `(b, a)`:

```
Arrays.sort(itemDetails, (b, a) ->
    String.valueOf(a.getAvailableQuantity())
          .compareTo(String.valueOf(b.getAvailableQuantity())));
```

Actually change names to meaningful so sorting logic will be understandable

Comment: I would recommend against doing something as subtle as flipping the parameter order: it looks like a typo, TBH. If you're going to do something like this, I would reverse the order you use the arguments inside the lambda body.

Comment: @AndyTurner added comment `Actually change names to meaningful so sorting logic will be understandable`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Comparator.comparing` (to avoid having to repeat the `String.valueOf` and `getAvailableQuantity`) and `Comparator.reversed()` (to clearly convey the fact that you are reversing the sort order):

```
Arrays.sort(
    itemDetails,
    Comparator.comparing((ItemDetails a) -> String.valueOf(a.getAvailableQuantity())).reversed());
```

where `ItemDetails` is the name of the element type of the array (or some supertype which also has the `getAvailableQuantity` method).

Comment: thanks but this is not working in my case giving me a error of typecasting of object.

Comment: @Shubhi Add the type of the array element to the lambda parameter, e.g. `(ItemDetail a) -> `. [Demo](https://ideone.com/Z3pOa6)

Comment: I added it but that is giving me runtime error. @ Andy Turner

Answer (score 1):

Add a minus:

```
Arrays.sort(itemDetails, (a, b) -> -String.valueOf(a.getAvailableQuantity()).compareTo(String.valueOf(b.getAvailableQuantity())));
```

Comment: What if `compareTo` had returned `Integer.MIN_VALUE`?

Comment: @AndyTurner it will not. But if that's a concern for you, you can also swap a and b.

Comment: It might not in this specific case, so you can use this "one weird trick" here, but it should come with a health warning that you shouldn't do it in the general case.

Comment: @AndyTurner fair enough